# Circular image view not wrapping image as circle

Tags: android

I am using the Circular Image View to place the profile image. Its showing fine in the preview of the android studio but when checking at mobile devices the circular image view is not working properly. The image of the problem is shown below:

[image]

I have tried as follows:

My gradle dependency:

```
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
```

My Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5"
tools:context=".Fragment.AccountFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_user" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/register"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@string/register"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/darkGray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/register"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/ride_summary"
            android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/darkGray" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/documents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/register"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/document"
            android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/darkGray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/payment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/register"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/payment"
            android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@color/darkGray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have set image as follows:

```
 try {
        URL url = new URL(image);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmapFrmUrl = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapFrmUrl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    }
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView it's best for circle Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i personally like to use the de.hdodenhof plugin, really simple to implement. Just add the following to your gradle (module: app) implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'  and then the following to your xml

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#80ffffff"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Glide Library with Circular Transformations

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
        .centerCrop()
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
        .error(R.drawable.user);

Glide.with(context)
        .load(user.getProfilePicUrl())
        .apply(options)
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .into(viewHolder.userImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

use circle image library like this.

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_user" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First use this into Build:Gradle (Module:app) :

```
dependancies {
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}
```

2. Then Use this in your .xml :

   ```
   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
       android:id="@+id/profileImage"
       android:layout_width="120dp"
       android:layout_height="120dp"
       android:padding="3dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_dummy_user"/>
   ```
3. If it is not working try this and check again :

> Build -> Make Project